# ModelMap attribute not passing the value

Tags: spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am having issues with modelmap attributes.. this is my xyz.jsp file..

```
<select name="list">
   <option value="-">Choose a Value</option>
   <c:forEach items="${sectionList}" var="section">
   <option value="${section.code}">${section.description}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

and the controller class...

```
 @RequestMapping(value="index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String mainList(ModelMap modelMap){
     modelMap.addAttribute("sectionList", sectionService.getAllSectionList());
     return "home";
  }
```

But on the web page I don't see the options in the drop down.. All I see is only one value saying "${section.description}".. infact this is the source in html..

```
<select name="division" >
  <option value="-">Choose a Value</option>
  <option value="${section.code}">${section.description}</option>
</select>
```

Any help on what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: for future reference mistake was in web.xml.. I was using incorrect header with version 2.3 where as my servlet version was 2.5.. I changed it to correct schema and now it works as expected

Answer (score 2):

did you try `<c:out value="${section.[attribue]}/>`? otherwise it will be displayed as string.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you dont have **jstl-{version}.jar** in your lib folder.

Comment: @Kalyan.. I have it.. infact this in my jsp <head> works fine   `<title> ${param.title}</title>`