# ModelMap not passing beans to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I`ve got a problem with my app.Im using SpringMVC, Maven, Hibernate. Simply im trying to print some data in jsp view.
 My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>app</display-name> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String generateMainPage(ModelMap model)
{
    UserModel um = new UserModel();
    // setting UserModel data which are 100% not null
    String simpleString = "hello "+new Date().toString();
    int simpleNumber = 1234;
    model.addAttribute("userModel", um);
    model.addAttribute("string", simpleString);
    model.addAttribute("number", simpleNumber);
    return "mainPage";
}
```

My model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Now, the problem is that my jsp not returning values **ONLY** from beans. I have found a similar problem [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970897/modelmap-attribute-not-passing-the-value) but it isn`t solved anything.

Part of my jsp "mainPage" page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome page</title>
</head>
<body>
     ${simpleString} <br/> <!-- this works fine -->
     ${simpleNumber} <br/> <!-- this works fine also -->
     ${um.name} <!-- this return nothing -->
     ${um.age} <!-- same here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `userModel.name` in jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${um.name} <!-- this return nothing -->
```

it shoul dbe

```
${userModel.name}
```

because in controller you do this

```
model.addAttribute("userModel", um);
```

The string is the name of the attribute, it can be whatever you want